# Move clicked text to input text box

Tags: javascript

I have certain text elements in my HTML. I need to move the clicked text element to a certain input text box.
[The problem is described in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeVDr.png)

There is some text on the page( inside some specific division) and when I click on the text it should move inside the input box.

Comment: Cool. Have you tried anything? `click` event possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add an `onclick` handler to all elements with the "foo" class (your clickable `inputs`). The handler will append the clicked text to the end of the existing text in the `out` element, preceding it with a space character if the `out` element is not empty.

```js
const outElem = document.getElementById("out");
for (let f of document.getElementsByClassName("foo")) {
  f.onclick = (e) => {
    outElem.value += (outElem.value ? ' ' : '') + e.target.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="foo" id="t1" value="text1"><input class="foo" id="t2" value="text2"><input class="foo" id="t3" value="text3"><br>
<textarea id="out"></textarea><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the element's `value` and `innerText` properties and event listeners.

```js
const src = document.getElementsByClassName("source");
const dest = document.getElementById("dest");

for (let i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
  src[i].addEventListener("click", e => 
    dest.value += " " + src[i].innerText
  );
}
```

```css
.source { 
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="source">text 1</span>
  <span class="source">text 2</span>
  <span class="source">text 3</span>
</div>
<input id="dest">
```